# What is the first tool to learn start your your data science projects?

Tags: python, statistics, ipython, descriptive-statistics, mathematics

What is the first tool  to learn start your your data science projects?

Answer (score 1):

This question was probably asked million times. Please try to find answers berfore you ask "where to **learn start**".